# Replacing asynchronous code block with method call cause bug in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, promise, refactoring

I have a method that is called during the created() life cycle hook. The content of this code block is a simple return Promise.all() execution which handles a few things inside the .then() block.

For example:

```
methodA() {
  return Promise.all([promise1, ..., promiseN]) {
    .then(([res1, ..., resN]) => {
      const getRes1 = res1.data
      const getResN = resN.data
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
}
```

What I try to do, do note that the .then() block has quite a big chunk of code for each resX.data, is refactor this in such a way, that some of the resX.data would be moved into their own functions. I need this, not only because it makes code tidier, but also because the same code can be used elsewhere in my program as a generic function to gather data into variables and so, help minimise code repetition.

I end up with something similar to this:

```
methodA() {
  return Promise.all([promise1, ..., promiseN]) {
    .then(([res1, ..., resN]) => {
      this.function1(res1.data)
      this.functionN(resN.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
}

function1(data) {
  // Do stuff with data
  this.globalVar1 = data
}

functionN(data) {
  // Do stuff with data
  this.globalVarN = data
}
```

When done this way, the data ends up not getting rendered in the view model. I am thinking this is because the Promise doesn't return the data in time but it is not a case of promise chaining, so I don't understand why this simple method change breaks my entire code.

EDIT:
The promises are external calls to either a local file or an API call.
The .then() code block does not return anything. It simply uses the data returned to assign values to global variables.

Comment: You haven't shown what the old code was returning from the fulfillment handler (the function you pass `then`) and what the new code returns from its fulfillment handler. We can't help you fix your new version without that, I'm afraid. :-)

Comment: Oh sorry about that! The new methods function1(), functionnN() do not return anything. They simply take the resX.data and assign values into some global variables. This is the reason that I believe it is a timeout issue of the Promise. Again, note that this is done in the created() life cycle hook and thus, before the mounted() hook.

Comment: The question was about the fulfillment handlers, not the new methods. (Although the fact the new methods don't return anything is probably useful information, too.)

Comment: Okay then, could you advice an edit to the question title itself or the description?

Comment: Yes: Show us what the fulfillment handlers are returning, as I said above.

Comment: As I mentioned, the only thing being returned is the Promise.all() call. Eveyrthing inside the .then() block is data manipulation coming from the external calls (API call, file access etc). The .then() block itself is not returning anything. Or am I completely missing your question?

Comment: The `then` callbacks aren't returning anything? Then we'll need a [mcve]. Please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make the MRE runnable. They support JSX and Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Please call the function in promiss.all param array:
ex:

```
async function example() {
  const start = Date.now()
  let i = 0
  function res(n) {
    const id = ++i
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(id)
        console.log(`res #${id} called after ${n} milliseconds`, Date.now() - start)
      }, n)
    })
  }

  const data = await Promise.all([res(3000), res(2000), res(1000)])
  console.log(`Promise.all finished`, data)
}
example();
```

Or Can you try this way?:

```
async handleAction() {
  await Promise.all([this.functionOne(), this.functionTwo()]);
}
```

```
async functionOne() {
  const response1 = await axios.get('http://localhost/abc/xyz');
  // Do sth with the data here
}
```

```
async functionTwo() {
  const response2 = await axios.get('http://localhost/abc/xyz');
  // Do sth with the data here
}
```

Comment: Did not work, the view is still not rendering with the information passed from the promise calls.

Comment: Also want to add, this is a collaborative project and the code does not use axios for external calls.

Comment: ok. So it may because some of promisse has been rejected or if not, I think your problem is related to Vue render and not from Promise.all
Please try to run the Code Snippet above to see.

Comment: Might be, I still think it is because of the created() life cycle, maybe parts of the code haven't been rendered or created in a way? Not sure.. I will take both answers and try to combine the best of both worlds, see if anything comes out of that. Thank you for your help!